# Cant find the newest environment: sdk version flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

The Flutter SDK was updated and I wanted to update the pubspec.yaml, but couldnt find what to put here:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-86.0.dev <4.0.0'
```

Does someone know a website, where I can find the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive to view the Dart version for a specific Flutter version.

Comment: But how can I get this:
>=2.12.0-86.0.dev <4.0.0
?